# How to add object name to table columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am receiving JSON array, flattening it to display it as a table, but this logic I am using has a flaw, if my object have same column name it will ignore it and will only add first column it finds.

**Problem I am trying to solve**

Display nested objects into a flat table

**Problem I am stuck at**

I want to add object's name to column header, which is not happening at the moment.

[image]

**I think problem is here**

```
  function flattenRecord(result, rec) {
    return Object.keys(rec).reduce(function(result, key) {
      var value = rec[key];
      if (value && typeof value === 'object')
        flattenRecord(result, value);
      else
        result[key] = value;  // How to add key here so that it will be added to column header ?
      return result;
    }, result);
  }
```

**Complete Code and Working Example**

https://jsfiddle.net/1tsu6xt9/14/

Comment: I guess you are looking for a way to flatten and unflatten objects.  [Like this library](https://github.com/hughsk/flat).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1tsu6xt9/20/  Line #56 Lol :D

Comment: @cswl my JSON data is dynamic so I can't hardcode keys, otherwise it would had been really easy ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue, I had to change logic of flattening JSON as suspected,

Changed FlattenRecord method to following,

```
  function flattenRecord2(data) {
    var result = {};

    function recurse(cur, prop) {
      if (Object(cur) !== cur) {
        result[prop] = cur;
      } else if (Array.isArray(cur)) {
        for (var i = 0, l = cur.length; i < l; i++)
          recurse(cur[i], prop);
        //if (l == 0)
          //result[prop] = [];
      } else {
        var isEmpty = true;
        for (var p in cur) {
          isEmpty = false;
          recurse(cur[p], prop ? prop + "." + p : p);
        }
        if (isEmpty && prop)
          result[prop] = {};
      }
    }
    recurse(data, "");
    return result;
  }
```

and following line too,

```
  var rows = testData.reduce(function(rows, row) {
    return appendRow(rows, flattenRecord2(row));
  }, []);
```